# VIM does not detect syntax of .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, vim, syntax-highlighting

On a plain Ubuntu installation (12.04 in my case) when I have no ~/.vimrc VIM does not detect syntax of .ssh/config.

Syntax highlighting works, but it does not set the correct filetype.

```
vi ~/.ssh/config
  :set syn?
  >syntax=conf
```

When I do:

```
set syn=sshconfig
```

Then the syntax highlighting is as it should be.

Why isn't the filetype automatically identified? And how can it be set automatically?

Comment: BTW, do others also have this problem? Or is it just me?

Comment: I have opened the Vim with the not existing file ~/.ssh/config and the filetype was sshconfig. I have complex settings for vim: https://github.com/horvatha/vimrc I tried it on 11.10. The .vimrc with just the row "filetype plugin on" is not enough: it does not set the filetype for that file.

Answer (score 1):

Does putting the following in ~/.vimrc help?

```
filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the vim that comes with a plain Ubuntu installation lacks autocmd.

Install vim completely with `sudo apt-get install vim` and you should be set.